# UICollectionView, is ReloadData() reload header and footer?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uicollectionview

Is the ReloadData() method reload the header and the footer or only cells ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReloadData` will reload all the sections , and Section = header + cell + footer.

This method will invoke all the delegate methods you have set.If you override `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` , then it will relaod header and the footer.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple Docs.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618078-reloaddata

This Detail copy Apple website.

Call this method sparingly when you need to reload all of the items in the collection view. This causes the collection view to discard any currently visible items (including placeholders) and recreate items based on the current state of the data source object. For efficiency, the collection view only displays those cells and supplementary views that are visible. If the collection data shrinks as a result of the reload, the collection view adjusts its scrolling offsets accordingly.

You should not call this method in the middle of animation blocks where items are being inserted or deleted. Insertions and deletions automatically cause the table’s data to be updated appropriately.